# Having an Issue of loader on product page in magento2.4.1

Tags: magento, magento2

I have an issue which is loader still loading in product detail page when i migrate magento 2.4.0 to magento 2.4.1

am expecting to load product detail page properly

Answer (score 0):

issue is not coming display none or hide  in loader div

```html
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask">
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Fix for jumping content. Loader must be the same size as gallery.-->
<script>
    var config = {
            "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $width; ?>,
            "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $thumbHeight ?: $thumbWidth; ?>,
            "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
            "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $height; ?>
        },
        thumbBarHeight = 0,
        loader = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder"] [data-role="loader"]')[0];

    if (config.navtype === 'horizontal') {
        thumbBarHeight = config.thumbheight;
    }

    loader.style.paddingBottom = ( config.height / config.width * 100) + "%";
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).